# Tips for diagnosing MacBook Pro WiFi connectivity issues

Tags: wireless-networking, macbook

I've got a MacBook Pro, and I notice that after a while on my home WiFi network (WPA2, PSK, Belkin N+ router) that I can't surf.  The airport connection appears strong, I can zip around my own local network just fine, but it appears as though I can't access external websites.

This issue doesn't occur on any of my other (Windows/Linux) machines, so it's got to be something to do with the MacBook, or so I figure. Only thing I've thought of thusfar is traceroute, which yields either really long ping times (> 1000 ms) or timeouts.

If anyone can help me diagnose this, or if they know the answer to this, it'd be muchly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem yesterday. Running Network Utilities (in /Applications/Utilities) cured the problem.

Comment: Just running it solved it?  Without doing anything inside of the application?

Comment: yes. Just running it. I didn't do anything inside the application.